# Table with multiple foreign keys can become invalid

Tags: database-design, foreign-keys

I have various types of tasks.  Each task type has a given set of properties.  Tasks are created and the values of the properties are assigned.

The database design for this is:

*TaskType (pk_taskType, name)*

*TaskTypeProperty (pk_taskTypeProperty, fk_taskType, name)*

*Task (pk_task, fk_taskType, name)*

*TaskProperty (pk_taskProperty, fk_task, fk_taskTypeProperty, value)*

[image]

Everything works, but there is the potential that given a Task, one can change the TaskType reference and NOT change the Properties.  This is invalid, yet the database is still happy.

Is there a better schema to represent this scenario and enforce it in the database?

Example Data:

[image]

If the fk_taskType is changed to 2 in the Task table, the database allows it but we know have properties associated to task T1 that are not correct properties.

Answer (score 0):

This should not have the problem, the idea is simply to make sure that task of a certain type is only allowed properties associated with that type.

---

**|** Task type `TYPE_ID` exists.

*Task type is identified by `TYPE_ID`.*

```
TaskType {TYPE_ID}
      PK {TYPE_ID}
```

**|** Property `PROP_ID` exists.

*Property is identified by `PROP_ID`.*

```
Property {PROP_ID}
      PK {PROP_ID}
```

**|** Task-type `TYPE_ID` is associated with property `PROP_ID`.

*It is possible for a task-type to be associated with more than one property, for each property
it is possible that more than one task-type is associated with that property.*

*If a task-type is associated with a property than that task-type must exist.*

*If a task-type is associated with a property than that property must exist.*

```
TaskTypeProperty {TYPE_ID, PROP_ID}
              PK {TYPE_ID, PROP_ID}

             FK1 {TYPE_ID} REFERENCES TaskType {TYPE_ID}
             FK2 {PROP_ID} REFERENCES Property {PROP_ID}
```

**|** Task `TASK_ID` is of task-type `TYPE_ID`.

*Each task is of exactly one task-type; for each task-type it is possible that more
than one task is of that task-type.*

*If a task is of a task-type, then that task-type must exist.*

```
Task {TASK_ID, TYPE_ID}
  PK {TASK_ID}

  AK {TASK_ID, TYPE_ID}   -- superkey, redundant here but needed in SQL
                          -- to be referenced by a FK

 FK1 {TYPE_ID} REFERENCES TaskType {TYPE_ID}
```

**|** Task `TASK_ID` of type `TYPE_ID` has property `PROP_ID`.

*It is possible for a task to have more than one property, for each property it is possible for more than one task to have that property.*

*If a task of a task-type has a property, than that property is associated with that task-type.*

*If a task has a property associated with a task-type than that task is of that task-type.*

```
TaskProperty {TASK_ID, PROP_ID, TYPE_ID}
          PK {TASK_ID, PROP_ID}

          FK1 {TASK_ID, TYPE_ID} REFERENCES Task {TASK_ID, TYPE_ID}   
          FK2 {TYPE_ID, PROP_ID} REFERENCES TaskTypeProperty {TYPE_ID, PROP_ID}
```

---

Notes:

```
PK = primary key
AK = alternate key (unique)
FK = foreign key
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the TaskProperty table at all. You have the TaskTypeProperty table which has an entry for each property of each type of task. I imagine that fields pk_taskTypeProperty and fk_taskType form the composite PK of that table (though I certainly hope you don't really name the columns "FK_..." or "PK_...").

So in the Tasks table, there should be a TaskType and TaskProperty field that form a FK to the TaskTypeProperty table. Now there cannot be a Task that is is not properly defined in the TaskTypeProperty table.

The Tasks table need not have a FK directly to the TaskType table. That chain of reference will go through the TaskTypeProperty FK to the TaskType table. That is a perfectly fine design. The purpose of foreign keys is data integrity enforcement, not to duplicate a line of inheritance from a UML graph. So reference the table(s) that satisfy that requirement.